# Why do we need ViewModelProvider.Factory to pass view model to a screen?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

I am new to Android development. Currently, I am using Jetpack Compose to build Android apps. I am also learning with MVVM architecture.

One thing I don't understand with this architecture is why we need to use `ViewModelProvider.Factory` to pass view model to a screen.

For example,

Instead of this,

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen() {
    val factory = object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            val repository = InMemoryPlantService()

            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return HomeViewModel(
                plantRepository = repository
            ) as T
        }
    }

    val homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel(null, factory)

    val currentState: State<HomeViewState> = homeViewModel.viewState.collectAsState()

    HomeScreenScaffold(currentState.value)
}
```

Can't we do this,

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen() {
    val repository = InMemoryPlantService()
    val homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = HomeViewModel(
        plantRepository = repository
    )

    val currentState: State<HomeViewState> = homeViewModel.viewState.collectAsState()

    HomeScreenScaffold(currentState.value)
}
```

Please help.

Full source code can be found here: https://github.com/adammc331/bloom

`HomeScreen` can be found here: https://github.com/AdamMc331/Bloom/blob/development/app/src/main/java/com/adammcneilly/bloom/HomeScreen.kt

Comment: Factory is used because viewmodel creation is conditional - it will only happen if `ViewModelProvider` does not contain given viewmodel.

Comment: I am sorry but is it possible you elaborate that statement a bit more? @Pawel

Answer (score 10):

When you call:

```
val homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel(null, factory)
```

The function `viewModel(...)` will create a new `HomeViewModel` if it's the first time you request the ViewModel, or it will return the previous instance of `HomeViewModel` if it already exists. That's one of the advantages of using ViewModels, because on configuration change (or on recomposition) your ViewModel should be reused, not created again. And the way it works is by using a `ViewModelProvider.Factory` to create the ViewModel when it's necessary. Your ViewModel has a parameter on its constructor, there's no way the default Android classes would know how to create your ViewModel and pass that parameter (i.e. the repository) without you providing a custom `ViewModelProvider.Factory`. If your ViewModel doesn't have any parameters, the default `ViewModelProvider.Factory` uses reflection to create your class by using the no-argument constructor.

If you do this:

```
val homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = HomeViewModel(
    plantRepository = repository
)
```

Your ViewModel will be created many times and won't be reused across configuration changes or recompositions because you're always creating it there - instead of asking for it to be created or reusing it if it already exists, which is what the `viewModel(...)` function does.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer @cd1. Just one question. If I leave a page I don't want the view model to store the data. I want the view model to be cleared. Does that mean in this case I don't use `viewModel` function? Instead just do `HomeViewModel(plantRepository = repository)`?

Comment: You should still use the viewModel function because your composable function HomeScreen might be called multiple times (for other reasons) and your ViewModel would be recreated for unexpected reasons. If you want to clear your ViewModel state when you leave the screen, I'd suggest creating a method like "clear()" on it and calling it when you leave the screen (e.g. when clicking on some button, back button, etc).

Comment: I just found out Jetpack compose has a remember function. So I guess I don’t have to use viewModel anymore. Just use remember { HomeViewModel(…) }.

Comment: @Axel bad idea mate, that's not the recommended way at all, the moment your Composable gets destroyed, the viewModel does too. That's the whole idea of viewModels. It survives the lifecycle of the app, but this way, you're limiting its life to a potentially pathetically tiny amount of being.

Answer (score 1):

As per a codelab in Room,

*By using viewModels and ViewModelProvider.Factory,the framework will take care of the lifecycle of the ViewModel. It will survive configuration changes and even if the Activity is recreated, you'll always get the right instance of the WordViewModel class.*

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use ViewModelProvider.Factory to instantiate your ViewModel.

Lets assume you have an Entity:

```
    @Entity(tableName = "user")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id") val userId: Long)
```

And a DAO for that entity:

```
 @Dao
interface UserDao {//some methods}
```

Without using a repository you can instantiate your ViewModel with the help of `android.app.Application` like so:

```
    class UserViewModel(
    application: Application
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
   val dao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).userDao()
}
```

And then later in a Fragment create your ViewModel which you can later pass into your composable:

```
private val userViewModel: userViewModel by viewModels()
```

Comment: Well, technically, this *is using* the factory, just doing it for you behind the scenes.